# Why do I get white screen when building flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to build a flutter web app, so I enter 'webdev build' command and after the operation finishes, I open the 'index.html' file located in build directory and it's just a white screen.
I tried it on a fresh project and the problem persists.
There's no problem during developing.

[image]

Here's my flutter doctor output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.766], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.35.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `webdev serve` command, it'll provide an address like `localhost:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080`. I've attached a screenshot after running `webdev serve` for one of my Flutter Web Project. It says *Serving web on `http://127.0.0.1:8080`* So you need to open that URL in Browser.

[image]

---

This answer was written when flutter-web was a separate project and webdev was the way to go for running your app.

Now you can use `flutter run -d chrome` to run it for Web.

Comment: Yes, but it just gives a server to do the developing.I need the output files.

Comment: What do you mean by output files? Elaborate please

Comment: Oh my mistake,I didn't pay attention to this part from the documentation,"run the application using a static HTTP server.". I was just opening the index.html not using it is server.Thank you bro!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you then you can mark it as accepted and upvote it. Another tip: if you want to host you flutter web app on GitHub pages then use Peanut plugin, which is hassle free way to achieve the same.

Comment: I'm gonna try it out Thanks

Comment: I am running webdev serve command still the url gives be blank screen. Can you please help

Comment: Can you post your pubspec?

Answer (score 10):

You have to upload your files to the server and put them inside the root folder.

If you want to put them in other folder, you have to edit the "index.html" file to tell hem the folder.

For example:
If you upload your files to "test" folder, you have to edit this line of "index.html":

```
<base href="/">
```

To

```
<base href="/test/">
```

Comment: awesome ,,, clap

Comment: for me worked with my base url on this base href tag...like... https://www.example.com/myapp/

Answer (score 8):

For me seemed to have been a problem with antivirus and running `flutter run -d chrome --release` solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I was in stable channel and doing below solve the issue:

```
flutter clean 

flutter pub get 

flutter pub cache repair
```

I hope solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.I used inspect code on chrome and checked **console** section.So there was error `not allowed to load local resource` and a Path to some file was like this:

```
import 'file:///C:/Users/../someFile.dart';
```

And by changing path to

```
import 'package:.../someFile.dart'
```

white screen gone and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't pay attention to this part from the documentation,"run the application using a static HTTP server.". I was just opening the index.html not using it is server.

Answer (score 1):

For me I was in `master` channel and doing below solve the issue:

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter run -d chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

just run  `flutter config --enable-web` in your command line and close your editor and after run the app again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was in master channel and doing below solve the issue:

```
flutter clean 

flutter pub get 

flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my app running as a blank page in Chrome. I've fixed it by re-creating a project with `flutter create .`:

1. move your `lib` directory and `pubspec.yml` file to a safe place.
2. then, delete the rest of the files and directories in your project directory.
3. run `flutter create .`.
4. move back in those files from step 1.

Answer (score 1):

form me was to replace

```
<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
```

to

```
<base href="">
```

in index.html file

Comment: currently, this does not work. Ended with error: Error: The base href in "web/index.html" must be absolute (i.e. start with "/"), but found: `<base href="">`.