# After deploying on firebase flutter web project showing white blank page

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_application_1/homepage.dart';

   void main() {
   runApp(const MyApp());
   }

   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyApp({super.key});

    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
       title: 'Flutter Demo',
       theme: ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
       ),
       home: HomePage());
    }
    }
    ..........
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class CardItem {
   final String urlImage;
    final String title;
    final String subtitle;

    const CardItem({
   required this.urlImage,
   required this.title,
   required this.subtitle,
    });
      }

       class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 List<CardItem> items = [
   CardItem(
     urlImage:
         'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2529147/pexels-photo-2529147.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
     title: 'Nike Free Run',
     subtitle: '10',
   ),
   CardItem(
     urlImage:
         'https://underarmour.scene7.com/is/image/Underarmour/3024250-404_DEFAULT?rp=standard-30pad|gridTileDesktop&scl=1&fmt=jpg&qlt=50&resMode=sharp2&cache=on,on&bgc=F0F0F0&wid=512&hei=640&size=472,600',
     title: 'Adidad free run',
     subtitle: '\$50',
   ),
   CardItem(
     urlImage:
         'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRpozlaZ5vCRX6qz1ISfI7a2swqpFXvivy47jR1POAai3qom_f4KIMOB-gQoXdnzeLOUXk&usqp=CAU',
     title: 'Reebok',
     subtitle: '\$70',
   ),
   CardItem(
     urlImage:
         'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/pair-pink-sport-shoes-on-260nw-228691018.jpg',
     title: 'Puma',
     subtitle: '\$89',
   ),
   CardItem(
     urlImage:
         'https://images.creator-prod.zmags.com/image/upload/q_auto,dpr_2.625,f_auto/c_scale,w_300/621cf9017826497cf6ceb463.jpeg',
     title: 'Jordan',
     subtitle: '\$97',
   ),
 ];

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(),
     body: SingleChildScrollView(
       child: Column(
         children: [
           SizedBox(height: 3),
           Container(
             child: Align(
               alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
               child: Text(
                 'Category',
                 style: TextStyle(
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
           SizedBox(height: 0),
           Container(
             height: 300,
             child: ListView.separated(
               shrinkWrap: true,
               primary: false,
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
               scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
               itemCount: 5,
               separatorBuilder: (context, _) => SizedBox(
                 width: 12,
               ),
               itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                   buildCard(item: items[index], context: context),
             ),
           ),
           SizedBox(height: 0),
           Container(
             child: Align(
               alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
               child: Text(
                 'Category',
                 style: TextStyle(
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 // ignore: dead_code
 Widget buildCard({
   required CardItem item,
   required BuildContext context,
 }) =>
     Expanded(
       child: Container(
         height: 100,
         width: 200,
         child: Column(
           children: [
             Expanded(
               child: AspectRatio(
                 aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                 child: ClipRRect(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                   child: Material(
                     child: Ink.image(
                       image: NetworkImage(item.urlImage),
                       fit: BoxFit.cover,
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 4,
             ),
             Text(
               item.title,
               style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 24,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                   color: Colors.black),
             ),
             Text( item.subtitle,
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
             )
           ],
         ),
       ),
     );
}
```

Comment: am working on a flutter web project , after developing in vs code when i run in localhost it is working fine but after deploying in firebase on main domain it is showing white blank page on main url (Please help me out to resolve this issue ) ..............here is my git repo link please check this is single page website ===https://github.com/AbhiEntrepreneur/4dec_firebaseBlank

Answer (score 0):

doing the following steps solved my problem;

```
flutter clean 

flutter pub get 

flutter pub cache repair

flutter build web
```

Comment: tried same but still showing same blank page even you can try at your system

Comment: After doing these, I deploy, the white screen does not appear. You can also have a look here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613174/why-do-i-get-white-screen-when-building-flutter-web